# Stress test OpenVPN server?

Tags: openvpn

We have about 50-100 concurrent users connected to our current VPN and would like to migrate to an OpenVPN network. We have setup a RHEL server running OpenVPN and would like to simulate 50-100 concurrent users. Can you think of any methods we could use to do this? We dont have access to a huge array of hardware. Are there any online services which we could leverage perhaps? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a few dozen small Amazon EC2 instances?  They don't cost the earth, and would allow you to install a very basic linux desktop on, to connect back to the server under test.